# Delete pairs from dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary

```
Counter({'183019767': 1075, '291781172': 929, '24710024': 608, '211884417': 576, '154037610': 351, '165402000': 248, '20649754': 218, '134275433': 196, '110893265': 185, '261966422': 177, '5706248': 169, '30453150': 142, '132880803': 121,'324020417': 32, '18372999': 32, '332474699': 32, '1296153': 32, '85179': 31, '174448039': 31, '142345622': 30,  '151209537': 22, '135837721': 21, '64417676': 21, '350093413': 21, '189194442': 20, '40024441': 20, '8605568': 19, '9653942': 19, '38236943': 18, '136540780': 18, '142929569': 18, '68806963': 18)}
```

I need to delete pairs, where `value < 30`
I try

```
for keys in count_id:
    if count_id.values() < 30:
        del count_id[keys]
```

But it doesn't work. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying if the list is less than 30 instead of the value.

do `if count_id[keys] < 30:` instead

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a list to store all the keys whose values are less than 30 and then try deleting the elements from the dictionary.

```
li =[]
for key in count_id.keys():
     if count_id[key] <30:
        li.append(key)
for key in li:
    del count_id[key]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should also copy your dictionary before deleting values.

```
temp =count_id.copy()
for keys in count_id.keys():
    if count_id[keys] < 30:
        del temp[keys]
```

Comment: Wont this give a Error like  RuntimeError:dictionary changed size during iteration  ??

Comment: @San if you do not copy then you get the runtime error

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an error:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

You should either iterate over a copy of the Counter's keys:

```
for k in list(count_id.keys()):
    if count_id[k] < 30:
        del count_id[k]
```

Or create a new Counter:

```
new_count_id = Counter({k: v for k, v in count_id.iteritems() if v >= 30})
```